# i cant log into pokemon go on my iphone

Tags: pokemon-go

when i open the pokemon go app for my ios 9.3 iphone, the app takes me to a page where it only gives me the option to SIGN UP with google and not SIGN IN to my already existing account, furthermore when i click sign up it wont load the next page for me, ive already tried re-downloading the app, hard restart of the phone and simply closing and re-opening the app. nothing has worked so far

Answer (score 0):

There are only problems with the servers. There are more questions like yours that can maybe help you further.

Next time you can try to search before posting your question. Good luck!